# CLLocation didupdatetolocation not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, location

Spent few days trying to solve this but unable to find any solutions that works. I have checked all the post on stackoverflow and tried all their solutions and nothing seems to be working for. I have also tried the apple test project for CLLocation which works fine for me. I used bits and pieces from the apple test project

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LocateMe/Listings/README_md.html

But my code is not working at all. The DidupdateToLocation never gets called.

Here is my code (in viewDidLoad)

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;



// This is the most important property to set for the manager. It ultimately determines how the manager will

// attempt to acquire location and thus, the amount of power that will be consumed.

self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;



// Once configured, the location manager must be "started"

//

// for iOS 8, specific user level permission is required,

// "when-in-use" authorization grants access to the user's location

//

// important: be sure to include NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription along with its

// explanation string in your Info.plist or startUpdatingLocation will not work.

//

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



[self performSelector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocationWithMessage:)

           withObject:@"Timed Out"

           afterDelay:30];
```

I have checked to make sure locationServicesEnabled is enabled.

I have added NSLoationWhenInUseUsageDescription property to the info.plist file. Is there any other property I need to add or enable any services??

I cannot for the love of god figure out what i have done wrong. Can some one please help me with this.

Comment: btw the authorization alert pops up?

Comment: the authorisation alert does not pop up

Comment: Then I guess the didChangeAuthorizationStatus callback neither get called, right? The location service for the app is enabled? (Settings/Privacy/Location services) Are you sure you added the right key to your .plist?

Comment: hey david, yes I have checked that I am adding the right key to the plist. still cant get it to work. Had to put this on hold for a while. gonna try and fix it today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. I added the keywords to the wrong plist file. I have got it working now. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 6):

You have to call the startUpdatingLocation after you received the didChangeAuthorizationStatus callback on iOS8.

```
//iOS 8 API change
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}else{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

implement this delegate method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        {
            // do some error handling
        }
            break;
        default:{
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, don't forget, with IOS 8 you need to do `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`   plus `[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];`

```
_locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];

if(SYSTEM_IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

}

_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 //and the problem with your code : don't forget to start
_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and in your `didUpdateLocations`

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

        _currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0]; 
        //do your stuff with the location

    }
```

Comment: wonderful. Adding both `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and `requestAlwaysAuthorization` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just spend an entire morning on this [in honestly I am relative new OOC], anyway the problem..

didUpdateLocation compiles and is never called
didUpdateLocations compiles and does work!!

Not the answer in this case it would seem, but it is in the question, an easy mistake to make. Using IOS 8.1.3 & Xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Simply add three properties in Info.plist.

To get the current location, if it is not calling didUpdateToLocation method

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
privacy - location usage description` of type String.